# Find the original imported image path in Fireworks

Tags: adobe-fireworks

I have imported an image into fireworks but I cannot remember where it came from. I need to find the original in order to rescale the image. Is there a way to determine the original path.

ps. Cannot undo as the document was made 4 months ago.

Comment: It's been a while, but I don't think Fireworks links to external files...rather it just imports the file and makes it part of the fireworks document. In which case, there's really nothing we can do to help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can.
This extension could be usefull if you had it beforehand. I know it's no use for you now, but for next time :)
http://johndunning.com/fireworks/about/LinkedImages